# Importing uninstalled Python package inside bash script doesn't fail but its __file__ is None

Tags: python, bash

I am facing a weird situation I've never encountered before.

I have a bash script that contains the following line:

```
python -c "import foo; print(foo.__file__); import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

When I directly run this bash script, I am getting None for `foo.__file__` and the package points to some "_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object" that's confusing to me:

```
None
--Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) foo
<module 'foo' (<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x7fbf30923790>)>
(Pdb) foo.__file__
```

But, when I run this line command on the terminal directly (not through a bash script), I get the following instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

What could account for such inconsistency?  (I am expecting the terminal output, that is, reporting ModuleNotFound, and not silently proceeds with a None `__file__` attribute)

Comment: I assume the module name isn't actually `foo`. Is this `foo` from a 3rd party library or is it part of your own code base? When I run the command in WSL, I get the expected `ModuleNotFoundError`, so there's something specific to your enviornment that is causing this. I assume you are looking for help how to trouble shoot this and track it down, right?

Comment: Good question. It is a package under development. It was installed with `pip install -e .`